# Swf Editor open source?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Does any body provide me the IDE name, Editor.
(I have an application that i need to edit SWF to generate a new SWF by Saving it)which helps to edit and saving capability for .SWF which was for free 
I had tried so many IDEs listed below  , but all are just trail ,
which does not have saving ability to SWF back.
Sothink system, 
Flash decompiler , 
Swf editor in sourcefourge , 
Falshdevelop ?..

can any body please suggest me!...

Comment: It looks like you rushed through typing "FlashDevelop" as fast as you did your research as that is just an IDE. Please use google and do more research before asking on the forums here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash is a free open source decompiler for swf files...

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply!..I have an application that i need to edit SWF to generate a new SWF  by Saving it!.. do u know any edit or this editor works ?...

Comment: its easy as piece of cake!

Comment: you can convert your swf to fla and after edit publish as new swf

Comment: hey , it reply helped me to convert the SWF files but can u also look at this thread , that i had posted , it will be great if had give any inputs on that!..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279238/convert-as3-to-fla-for-generating-swf

Comment: @ramakri its just bytes, so anything thats just bytes can be edited